# Numbers show at beginning of phpword document

Tags: php, phpword

I am just starting to work with this class file and am using the sample code file, but my output is including an odd number at the beginning of the output file.  I'm not sure where it comes from.  Can anyone assist on removing it? Thanks in advance.

Output looks like this (I have the numbers in bold):

**.511811024.795275591** "Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. The important thing is not to stop questioning." (Albert Einstein)......etc.

test.php:

```
<?php
//testing the phpword functionality to get it to output and format correctly

require_once 'includes/vendor/phpoffice/phpword/bootstrap.php';

// Creating the new document...
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

/* Note: any element you append to a document must reside inside of a Section. */

// Adding an empty Section to the document...
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
// Adding Text element to the Section having font styled by default...
$section->addText(
    '"Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow. '
    . 'The important thing is not to stop questioning." '
    . '(Albert Einstein)'
);

/*
 * Note: it's possible to customize font style of the Text element you add in three ways:
 * - inline;
 * - using named font style (new font style object will be implicitly created);
 * - using explicitly created font style object.
 */

// Adding Text element with font customized inline...
$section->addText(
    '"Great achievement is usually born of great sacrifice, '
    . 'and is never the result of selfishness." '
    . '(Napoleon Hill)',
    array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10)
);

// Adding Text element with font customized using named font style...
$fontStyleName = 'oneUserDefinedStyle';
$phpWord->addFontStyle(
    $fontStyleName,
    array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10, 'color' => '1B2232', 'bold' => true)
);
$section->addText(
    '"The greatest accomplishment is not in never falling, '
    . 'but in rising again after you fall." '
    . '(Vince Lombardi)',
    $fontStyleName
);

// Adding Text element with font customized using explicitly created font style object...
$fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
$fontStyle->setBold(true);
$fontStyle->setName('Tahoma');
$fontStyle->setSize(13);
$myTextElement = $section->addText('"Believe you can and you\'re halfway there." (Theodor Roosevelt)');
$myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyle);

/*// Saving the document as OOXML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');

// Saving the document as ODF file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'ODText');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.odt');

// Saving the document as HTML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.html');*/

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'RTF');
$objWriter->save('testdoc.rtf');

?>
```

Comment: thats in the word file?

Comment: Yes it shows at the beginning of the file output when I open it in word.  And if I try to use the Word2007 format for docx file, it gives me an XMLWriter error, even though it's on the server so that's why I'm using RTF.

Comment: do you really need RTF output? A lot of functionalities are not implemented for that format

Comment: I'm using RTF because I get an error on the XMLWriter I can't seem to resolve, but in answer to your question, no I don't have to use RTF.  It's just what I got to actually produce output at this point.

Comment: Just ran your code (but wrote it to docx with Word2007-Writer instead of RTF) and the doc opened just fine and there was no number at the beginning. And the code looks fine to me. So I think your problem might be elsewhere if you can reproduce this bug...

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the page width & height having a decimal places which go into the RTF document. I've submitted a pull request with a fix here https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/pull/1459